# Assembly Language: Writing modified byte values into a file pointer

Tags: assembly, xor, file-writing

I am extremely new to assembly language programming. I have the below code which is to write a set of bytes to a file pointer:

```
mov     cx,OFFSET ENDMYCODE - OFFSET MYCODE     ; write the MYCODE; cx=number of bytes to write
lea     dx,[di+MYCODE]
mov     ah,40H                                  ;DOS write function
int     21H
```

As I understand the above code write all the byte values in MYCODE to the file. I wanted to know if its possible to modify these bytes as and when it is written to the file i.e. a simple XORing of the bytes before it is written into the file pointer? And it should not XOR the original MYCODE byte values but just the one that I write to the file. Is it possible?

Te below is what I have come up with but it seems to be running into an infinite loop and I'm not able to debug it:

```
ENCRYPT:
        mov si, OFFSET MYCODE + 1
        mov di, OFFSET MYCODE + 1
        mov cx, OFFSET MYCODE - OFFSET MYCODE - 2
ELP:    lodsb
        xor al, 09Ah                                                                    ; XOR the byte values and then write to the file
        mov BYTE PTR [di+TEMPBUFFER],al
        push cx
        mov cx, 1
        lea     dx,[di+TEMPBUFFER]
        mov     ah,40H                                  ;DOS write function
        int     21H
        pop cx
        loop ELP

        mov cx, 1
        lea dx, [di+ENDMYCODE]
        mov ah,40h
        int 21h
```

Thanks

Comment: You will have to copy your bytes to a temporary buffer and modify them there. Alternatively, if this code is not part of the bytes you want to write, you can XOR them in place, write to file, then XOR them back.

Comment: Could you let me know how to implement that temp buffer? Because MYCODE is pretty long and I'm not sure of how to do that.

Comment: If it's long, and this piece of code is part of it, it may be easier to just copy this short code somewhere.

Comment: ENCRYPT:
        mov si, OFFSET MYCODE + 1
        mov di, OFFSET MYCODE + 1
        mov cx, OFFSET ENDMYCODE - OFFSET MYCODE - 2
ELP:    lodsb
        xor al, 09Ah                                                                   ; XOR the byte values and then write to the file
        mov BYTE PTR [di+TEMPBUFFER],al
        push cx
        mov cx, 1
        lea     dx,[di+TEMPBUFFER]
        mov     ah,40H                                  ;DOS write function
        int     21H
        pop cx
        loop ELP
        mov cx, 1
        lea dx, [di+ENDMYCODE]
        mov ah,40h
        int 21h

Comment: is there any problem in the above code? Will it work?

Comment: It looks like there is some error in this. My code is running into an infinite loop and I'm not able to debug it.

Comment: I have pasted my code above for readability.